# KSQL CLI vs Java Client - Stream access issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I created a stream with the KSQLDB client Java:

```java
        CompletableFuture<ExecuteStatementResult> execFuture = client.executeStatement(
                "CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS PAGEVIEWS " +
                "(PAGE_ID BIGINT, VIEWTIME BIGINT, USER_ID STRING) " +
                "WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='keyless-pageviews-topic', " +
                "KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');",
                properties
        );
```

However, when I try to read the data with the same Java client I can't see the data. However KSQL-CLI can see the data. Here's the java code that doesn't work:

```java
        String pullQuery = "select * from PAGEVIEWS emit changes;";

        StreamedQueryResult streamedQueryResult = client.streamQuery(pullQuery, properties).get();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Block until a new row is available
            Row row = streamedQueryResult.poll();
            if (row != null) {
                System.out.println("Received a row!");
                System.out.println("Row: " + row.values());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Query has ended.");
            }
        }
```

Can you please point out the issue here?

I can insert data to this same stream, and also monitor data with the same above pull query. Just this Java code doesn't work for the data reading. Need to get this reading part issue fixed.